# Plotly, add border around points created with add_markers

Tags: r, border, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I'm trying to create a `plotly` scatter plot with border around points.

The ideal thing is:

```
plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length,
        marker = list(size = 10,
                       color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                       line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                   width = 2)))
```

[image]

But in my (much more complicated) case I'm creating the plot with `add_markers` function like that:

```
plot_ly(data = iris) %>% 
             add_markers(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length,
                           color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)')
```

With that the `line` argument gives the line instead of border around points:
[image]

Adding `symbol = "circle-open"` as parameter doesn't help either.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide these properties as a `list` to the argument `marker`:

```
plot_ly(data = iris) %>% 
             add_markers(x = ~Sepal.Length, 
                         y = ~Petal.Length,
                         marker = list(
                                  color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193,0.5)',
                                  line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                              width = 2)
                                   )
             )
```

[image]