# Plotly Polar Plot Visualization in R

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I'm using `plotly` in `R` to create a polar plot but not sure why the output looks a little odd. It seems to not encapsulate the max points in the geometric lines despite showing up as individual points. Is there a way to right this/ is something about my code (below) incorrect?

[image]

```
fig <- plot_ly(type = 'scatterpolar',
               mode = 'lines') 

fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    r = proj_cell_FA_h2_df$Enrichment,
    theta = proj_cell_FA_h2_df$cell_type,
    name = 'test',
    mode = 'markers',
    fill = 'toself'
  ) 

fig <- fig %>% layout(polar = list(
  radialaxis = list(
    visible = T,
    range = c(0,3),
    dtick = 1
  )
),
showlegend = F
)

fig
```

Code shown above, was expecting the geometric shape/linear outline to encapsulate the maximum points but it seems only the markers/dot points were visible - why?

Comment: With "encapsulating the maximum points", do you mean the point markers should have a distinct border? Please also supply some example data from `proj_cell_FA_h2_df$Enrichment`, here's why: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If "encapsulating the maximum points" means "drawing points with borders", please see whether this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706258/plotly-add-border-around-points-created-with-add-markers (if so, please retract your question as duplicate)

Comment: Hi, no I don't mean borders around individual circle dot points. I meant, shouldn't the lines of the plot be extending out to the maximum value for each category, since there are values (as shown by the dots) up to 3 (for example, "Endo" category)?

Answer (score 1):

Without the [required example data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to tell, but it looks like you're trying to trace a line through numerous r-values per theta. So plotly attempts to derive a meaningful central r per theta (maybe the mean or median).

In that case you could use *two* traces, one for the points, and one connecting the extreme points (only). Considering the `iris` dataset:

```
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)
    
    iris_summary <- 
        iris |>
        summarise(Sepal.Length = max(Sepal.Length), .by = Species)
        
    plot_ly(type = 'scatterpolar',
            mode = 'markers') |>
        add_trace(
            data = iris_summary,
            r = ~ Sepal.Length,
            theta = ~ Species,
            fill = 'toself',
            name = 'max sepal length'
        ) |>
        add_trace(
            data = iris,
            r = ~ Sepal.Length,
            theta = ~ Species,
            name = 'sepal length'
        )
```

[image: radar chart]